# How to combine cucumber reports from multiple machines

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, rest-assured

I am doing parallel execution of selenium tests in different machines using Jenkins.

The "cucumber.json" file will be generated in each machine after the execution of the tets.

**please suggest me an approach to combine all cucumber reports from all machines and generate one report and send an email.**